# How to get the mean of a variable by group, and produce a new variable in the data_table taking that value

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, average

I have found so many solutions to other questions about the `dplyr` `group_by()` function in R, like the one below which suggests the `summarize_each()` function to simply print the `mean` of all variable observations for each conditionally defined group of rows in a dataset.

Unfortunately, I need to be able to create a new variable to attach to each row which is the average value of a measurement (in this example females' height) so that I can later use it as a predictor variable in a regression.

Are there any different solutions to this example that would allow someone to run a regression/classification process based on the group's average value (of height in this example)?

```
DF <- data.frame(Height = rnorm(100, 170, 5),
                 Weight = rnorm(100, 55, 5),
                 Gender = c(rep("male", 50), rep("female", 50)))


BMI <-  function(height,weight){(weight/(height)^2*10000)}

library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  mutate(bmi = BMI(Height, Weight)) %>% 
  summarise(mean_bmi = mean(bmi))
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why using `group_by` and `mutate` together then running the regression is not what you're looking for?

Comment: This might be the solution - I can't say I know how to go about trying it.  In this solution, the group_by() and mutate() together seems to produce the desired results in the summarize() table which is produced after you run this code. However, I don't know how to reference this information in a regression - all this code does is produce a summary table with the desired mean values for each group - it does not add these values to the data_table so I can call it up later in the regression model_form as I would any other variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `summarise` line of code. You can add `mean` directly into your `mutate`.

```
DF <- DF %>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  mutate(bmi = mean(BMI(Height, Weight))) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Then you can run your regression model with this dataset.

Comment: Thanks for this response - I tried to implement this now and it runs without any errors, so I believe that the function is indeed producing the values I need.  The only problem is, I am using a large dataset (1 million + rows) and so I am trying to avoid any manual inputs.   Even though this code does get me the values I need.  However, when I exclude the summarize() line like you suggest here, I still do not see any bmi variable when I run the view() function.  I need the bmi variable to be a new variable where the value will be the same value (the group average) for all 'female' group rows.

Comment: So far with this solution you propose, I would still need to add the summarize() line and manually create a new variable where for each line in the 'female' group, the value assigned is the average/mean bmi value for all females, etc...  What I am trying to do is automate this step of setting up the new variable that has a value equal to the average/mean values that are produced in the solution I included in the original question. So unfortunately this is not a solution to my original question because I still would not be able to include bmi in the regression y ~ x1 (bmi), x2, x3... setup

Comment: What I have been trying to do is adjust the first line of the pipeline to be:  DF$bmi <- DF %>%... but when I do that I get the following error: Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 48 items to be assigned to 1003681 items of column 'bmi'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

Comment: I'll try and address each comment. 
1. The code I originally provided does not save back to the data frame `DF`. I've updated the code now so it does and you should see it when using `View()`
2. Now that #1 is saving back to the data frame `DF` you will have a new variable called `bmi` and you can run your regression.
3. `DF$bmi <- DF %>% ` was close. But what you needed was `DF <- DF %>% ` like the change I made for #1.

Comment: Yes! That seems to have worked perfectly, thank you. This answers my original question. I had tried this before asking my question here, but I believe that because one of the variables - height or weight - had some missing (NA) values, and so the result was a column of NA values in a bmi column. I suppose that I assumed there was a problem with this line of code, though I see now that it the issue causing those NA missing values was due to missing values in the granular variables.  Thank you so much, this is so helpful!

Comment: Don't forget that `mean()` has an argument `na.rm` where you can ignore missing values. An example would be `mean(BMI(height, weight), na.rm = T)`